# How to get text from span tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

I have links looks like this

```
<div class="systemRequirementsMainBox">
<div class="systemRequirementsRamContent">
<span title="000 Plus Minimum RAM Requirement">1 GB</span> </div>
```

I'm trying to get `1 GB` from there. I tried

```
tt  = [a['title'] for a in soup.select(".systemRequirementsRamContent span")]
for ram in tt:
    if "RAM" in ram.split():
        print (soup.string)
```

It outputs `None`.

I tried `a['text']` but it gives me KeyError. How can I fix this and what is my mistake?

Comment: Can you share the surrounding html? (or the url)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes just a  min please

Comment: Also try `soup.select_one("span[title*=RAM]").text` and if you are iterating over the list you already have the text

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well, that worked. Could you post it as an answer please, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `bs4.select()` outputs a Tag object?  What does this code do:

`tt = [title for title in soup.select(".systemRequirementsRamContent span[title]")]`

Comment: contents[0]' after iterating over all the tags in the folder.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a css selector, pulling the span you want using the title text :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div class="systemRequirementsMainBox">
<div class="systemRequirementsRamContent">
<span title="000 Plus Minimum RAM Requirement">1 GB</span> </div>""", "xml")

print(soup.select_one("span[title*=RAM]").text)
```

That finds the *span* with a *title* attribute that contains *RAM*, it is equivalent to saying in python, `if "RAM" in span["title"]`.

Or using *find* with *re.compile*

```
import re
print(soup.find("span", title=re.compile("RAM")).text)
```

To get all the data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
r  = requests.get("http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=21580&game=000%20Plus").content

soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")
cont = soup.select_one("div.systemRequirementsRamContent")
ram = cont.select_one("span")
print(ram["title"], ram.text)
for span in soup.select("div.systemRequirementsSmallerBox.sysReqGameSmallBox span"):
        print(span["title"],span.text)
```

Which will give you:

```
000 Plus Minimum RAM Requirement 1 GB
000 Plus Minimum Operating System Requirement Win Xp 32
000 Plus Minimum Direct X Requirement DX 9
000 Plus Minimum Hard Disk Drive Space Requirement 500 MB
000 Plus GD Adjusted Operating System Requirement Win Xp 32
000 Plus GD Adjusted Direct X Requirement DX 9
000 Plus GD Adjusted Hard Disk Drive Space Requirement 500 MB
000 Plus Recommended Operating System Requirement Win Xp 32
000 Plus Recommended Hard Disk Drive Space Requirement 500 MB
```

Comment: Btw I tried `soup.select_one("span[title*=Space]").text` on this to get 500 MB`<span title="000 Plus Minimum Hard Disk Drive Space Requirement">500 MB</span> <div class="systemRequirementsTickOrCross"></div>` but it prints `HDD Space` that I don't understand why.

Comment: can you add a link to the html/url? I think there may be another spans title that contains the text Space

Comment: Oh well that's because there are span tags with Disk and their texts are `HDD Space`. How can I point that I want only span tags in the game's link?

Comment: I mean I have to point that this class `systemRequirementsSmallerBox sysReqGameSmallBox` which is holding the text I want.

Comment: `soup.select_one("div.systemRequirementsSmallerBox.sysReqGameSmallBox span[title*=Space]")` but if you are finding multiple things in that first find `soup.select_one("div.systemRequirementsSmallerBox.sysReqGameSmallBox")` then do you select_ones from that

Comment: This is the link btw view-source:http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=21580&game=000%20Plus if you ctrl+f and search for `Disk` you'll see

Comment: If you search for `Disk` 5th one I'm talking about, and many thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries, do you specifically want the one or all the `div.systemRequirementsSmallerBox.sysReqGameSmallBox` spans?

Comment: I saw you edited your answer and that's really looks elegant. I should practice more CSS probably, thanks for the help.

Comment: I used `soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")` because I couldn't install lxml, but it gives me this error when I try to `print (span.text)` `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: I ran the code with html.parser, are you running the code  as posted?

Comment: Well I figured out, I used `select` instead of `select_one` and it's ok now.

Comment: Cool, no worries. As far as css goes, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors shows you a lot of what you can use in bs4, the only pseudo-class implemented is nth-of-type but *= ^= >  + ~ etc.. are available to use.

Comment: used "html.parser" instead of "xml" did the job.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to extract the text inside all the span tags inside the HTML document using `find_all()` function from `bs4` (BeautifulSoup):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url="YOUR_URL_HERE"
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,html5lib)
spans=soup.find_all('span',"ENTER_Css_CLASS_HERE")
for span in spans:
  print(span.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `span` tag in BeautifulSoup or you can include other attributes like `class`, `title` along with the `span` tag.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML

htmlText = """<div class="systemRequirementsMainBox">
<div class="systemRequirementsRamContent">
<span title="000 Plus Minimum RAM Requirement">1 GB</span> </div>"""

soup = BSHTML(htmlText)
spans = soup.findAll('span')
# spans = soup.findAll('span', attrs = {'class' : 'your-class-name'}) # or span by class name
# spans = soup.findAll('span', attrs = {'title' : '000 Plus Minimum RAM Requirement'}) # or span with a title
for span in spans:
    print span.text
```

Comment: Why need to initiate a for loop for Beuatifulshop resultset even there is only one value?

Comment: @GautamShahi you don't need it for the given example. However, I keep it in general in case you have other span values that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with just a couple lines of [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

html = """\
<div class="systemRequirementsMainBox">
<div class="systemRequirementsRamContent">
<span title="000 Plus Minimum RAM Requirement">1 GB</span> </div>
"""

soup = Soup(html)
soup.find("span", {"title": "Minimum RAM Requirement"}).text
# '1 GB'
```