# Python Beautiful Soup tag.string

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following problem with Beautiful Soup. I didn´t found a solution, but I´m a total beginner (started this week with Python).

I want to get the string of this HTML-Tag:

```html
<dd class="is24qa-nebenkosten grid-item three-fifths"> <span class="is24-operator">+</span> 140 € </dd>
```

tag.string returns "None", allthough there is "140 €" behind the span-tag. 
How do I get the string "140 €"?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133759/how-to-get-text-from-span-tag-in-beautifulsoup

Comment: post your code and what have you tried so far

Comment: try `<tagname>.text` instead of `string`;  `print soup.find('dd', attrs={'class': 'is24qa-nebenkosten grid-item three-fifths'}).text` --> `140 €`

Comment: tag.text worked, thank you :)