# Python - Extract string from website with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract a string from a HTML source with only beautifulsoup. I am trying to extract: "1 van de maximaal 3 actieve reacties" from the following HTML:

```
<span class="titel ng-scope" translate="ReactiesTitel-Titel-actieve" translate-values="getTranslationValues()">1 van de maximaal 3 actieve reacties</span>
```

My current code retrieves the entire span class, but I cannot find out how I can only extract the string, without the use of .split or some sort of string manipulation.

Current code:

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
x = soup.find('span', {'class':'titel ng-scope'})
print(x)
```

Comment: `print(x.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

---

If you have:

```
html = '<span class="titel ng-scope" translate="ReactiesTitel-Titel-actieve" translate-values="getTranslationValues()">1 van de maximaal 3 actieve reacties</span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

You can get `1 van de maximaal 3 actieve reacties` by:

```
soup.text
```

A similar thread, where I got the idea from is: [How to get text from span tag in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133759/how-to-get-text-from-span-tag-in-beautifulsoup).