# make a string cleaner in python

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

I have a string :

```html
<span class="sc-7ebdc9db-1 dAVCtE _137P- _35DXM P4PEa" data-qa-id="aditem_price"><span>11 €</span
</span>\n
 <span class="sc-7ebdc9db-1 dAVCtE _137P- _35DXM P4PEa" data-qa-id="aditem_price"><span>20 €</span></span>\n
 <span class="sc-7ebdc9db-1 dAVCtE _137P- _35DXM P4PEa" data-qa-id="aditem_price"><span>10 500 €</span>
</span>
```

And I want to remove everything except the amout of money need (so only 11€, 20€, 10500€)
I've tried multiple thing but it seems like everything that I try is not optimized and only work with the same amout of character.
Do you know how could I do it ?

I tried to delete the first 95 characters of each lines but its not optimal because the amount of char may change

Comment: Have you tried BeautifulSoup or Parsel?

Comment: I'm using beautiful soup to get this result but I don't know what to do next

Comment: You can get the text out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133759/how-to-get-text-from-span-tag-in-beautifulsoup